# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un valor a una celda de mi tabla usando un boton?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mvc

Les comento, en mi tabla tengo cuatro columnas, una con nombres, otra apellidos, otra con el contenido editable que corresponde a la edad (la columna tiene  contenteditable="true"), y una con un botón. Al botón yo le doy un valor un valor x (en este caso el value = 20, que corresponde a la edad), y cuando le hago clic al botón, quiero que me complete con el value que tiene el botón en la celda que tiene contenido editable (columna de edad). ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
<table>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>

                        <td id="nombre" style="text-align: center">Nombre</td>
                        <td id="apellido" style="text-align: center">Apellido</td>
                        <td name="edad" id="edad" style="text-align: center" contenteditable="true">Edad</td>
                        <td><button name="BotonValor" id="BotonValor" value="20" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" contenteditable="false">Default</button></td>
                    </tr>               
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Si ya hay algo escrito (por ejemplo, si a la celda le escribo "13") a la columna de edad, y hago clic en el botón, quiero que me pise el "13" y me coloque el valor que haya en el botón (en este caso se cambiaria a "20").

¿Es posible también hacerlo sin ir al controlador?

Cualquier camino me sirve y me ayudaría una banda.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con javascript podria hacer lo siguiente, la edad la puede ajustar desde el boton o desde la misma funcion, ya depende de lo que necesite.

```
<table>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>

                        <td id="nombre" style="text-align: center">Nombre</td>
                        <td id="apellido" style="text-align: center">Apellido</td>
                        <td name="edad" id="edad" style="text-align: center" contenteditable="true">Edad</td>
                        <td><button name="BotonValor" id="BotonValor" value="20" onclick="cambiarEdad(20)" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" contenteditable="false">Default</button></td>
                    </tr>               
            </tbody>
</table>


<script>
        
    function cambiarEdad(edad){
        document.getElementById("edad").innerHTML = edad;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Y si el valor es uno traído por el modelo (ejemplo: onclick="cambiarEdad(@p.valor)" por ejemplo), pero a la vez el valor o puede ser "20", o puede ser "#00000", esto me tiraria error, como lo puedo resolver? Intente convertir el "#00000" en un string pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: para el caso del valor del modelo, se envia entre comillas simples, `onclick="cambiarEdad('@p.valor')"` , pero no entiendo por que enviar  "#00000" en el valor de edad, ya seria validar el tipo de dato que se va a enviar, adicional si es mas de una fila, cada uno debe tener un id diferente para distinguir que registro es el que se va a modificar

Comment: Muchas gracias! me salvaste de una muy grande! Yo use "edad" como para que les sea un dato amigable o mas fácil de entender, pero ya con lo que me ayudaste me sirve!